# Filtering objects in a drop-down menu by their field (Django/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I'm taking up a web development project in Django, and due to my lack of experience with it in the past I'm having trouble understanding what certain lines of code do, let alone accomplish what I need to in Javascript. I also don't have that much javascript experience either, I've been learning.

So jumping right into this...
I've found a model called BookTitles and that model has a field called book_type. I need help with understanding how I can access this field within a javascript file and then use it for filtering purposes.

When the homepage is rendered in views.py, it generates and returns lists called booklist_latin and booklist_greek. Here's what that looks like (not sure if it's really helpful to see, but I wanted to ask if anyone could help me understand some of what's going on here.

```
        sorted_latin_books=sorted(BookTitles.objects.all(),key=lambda book: (book.book_type,book.title_of_book))
    booklist_latin= [book.title_of_book 
            for book in sorted_latin_books]
```

I'm kinda confused at what the last line is doing. booklist_latin is called in the html file for the homepage within a for loop, `{% for each in booklist_latin %}`and the value of {{ each }} is just the title_of_book for each book in the booklist. In other words, I know that booklist_latin is a list of book titles. it's just, that syntax doesn't quite make sense to me especially since a for loop is started within the brackets.

So back on topic... Filtering. I have three buttons that represent the type of text that someone would like to search for within a drop-down menu that will either show all of what's in booklist_latin or booklist_greek, depending on which button you select to declare the language. Then, main.js runs a function called configureform(e) when you click on one of the language buttons that configures the drop down menu for only texts in the language you specified. I actually noticed that in this function, all of the texts from both latin and greek are generated. However, all texts that aren't in the language that corresponds with the button a user clicked are given "display: none" hiding them from sight.

This is actually really similar to what I want to happen.

The difference is that I now have buttons that correspond with the type of text. But I've been trying to think about how I could somehow, within the main.js file, check the type of book, and filter the drop-down menu. Syntatically I don't really understand how to do that though.

I've been looking at how we filter by language in main.js, and this seems to be how it's done.

```
    var books = $("#textlist").find("[class$='book']");
books = books.add($("#booklist").find("[class$='bookthumb']"));
// Hide all text/book elements NOT part of the selected language:
books.not("[class*='" + lang + "']").css("display", "none");
// Show all which are part of the selected language:
books.filter("[class*='" + lang + "']").css("display", "block");
```

The id's make reference to components of to the html file. I don't think I have to include code from that but if it would help you all understand, I will include it.

But I have no classes in my html file called "book" or "bookthumb." What does the term "class" mean in this context? And also, why are "*=" and "$=" operators used?

I am imagining a variation of the filter() and not() methods as being exactly what I need. But syntactically I don't know how to make filter() and not() verify the type of book and use that as a condition for filtering.

As you can see I also revealed several questions relating to various aspects of Django and Javascript. If there's any documentation that you feel would help me understand these concepts in one swing, please send it over.

That's it. Sorry for this unbearably long question. If this really doesn't make sense, I will delete or edit (suggestions are helpful).

Comment: The for loop started in the brackets is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: I'd suggest that you stick to the topic, if you have multiple questions, don't be afraid to make them in multiple entries, but if you cram your entry with too much, it's difficult to get the right answer. Please edit.

Comment: coming soon. I'll divide this post up and then delete it.